# Query Activity - Merging Data Extensions with Different Column Names

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, dataextensions, sql, automationstudio

I have a Data Extension called “Merged Data Extension Newsletter” that has fields called

```
“FirstName”, “LastName”, “Email”, and “Id”
```

I am using ID as the Primary Key.
I have another Data Extension called “July Newsletter – Leads” that has fields called

```
“Lead:FirstName”, “Lead:LastName”, “Lead:Email”, and “Lead:Id”
```

I’m trying to create a SQL Query to merge the “July Newsletter – Leads” DE to the “Merged Data Extension Newsletter” and have Lead:FirstName map to First Name, Lead:LastName map to LastName etc.

I tried the following, but I got an “Incorrect syntax near 'Lead:'” error.

```
SELECT Lead:FirstName as FirstName, 
Lead:LastName as LastName, 
Lead:Email as Email,
Lead:Id as ID,
From [July Newsletter - Leads]
```

Is what I am trying to do possible or can you only merge Data Extensions with the exact same column names?

Comment: Put brackets around your field names [Lead:Lastname]

Comment: I changed the query to: SELECT[Lead:FirstName] as [FirstName], 
[Lead:LastName] as [LastName], 
[Lead:Email] as [Email],
[Lead:Id] as [ID],
From[July Newsletter - Leads] but then I get an "Invalid column name 'Lead:FirstName'". I doubled checked the July Newsletter DE and that is the correct name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can definitely "rename" your fields in the query to reflect another Data Extension's structure and send the values to it.

As [@EazyE](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/66853/eazye) suggested in the comment, you should wrap your fields with square brackets when you use keywords or special characters in the column names or identifiers (in your case it is a colon symbol). And then another missing thing is the comma after the last selected field - `[Lead:Id] AS ID,` so your query should look like this -

```
SELECT
[Lead:FirstName] AS FirstName, 
[Lead:LastName] AS LastName, 
[Lead:Email] AS Email,
[Lead:Id] AS Id
FROM [July Newsletter - Leads]
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked!